# Частично переведённое письмо об окончании конкурса

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, конкурс

Пришло письмо об окончании конкурса.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно по скрину, оно частично на русском, частично на английском.  Думаю, стоит перевести.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. https://ru.traducir.win/string/1052

   Предложил:

   > завершилось и будет автоматически закрыто после
   >   $AcceptGracePeriodHours$-часового периода.
2. https://ru.traducir.win/string/10809 и https://ru.traducir.win/string/6205

   Предложил:

   > Если вы считаете, что какой-либо из них заслуживает вознаграждения,
   >   присудите его нажав на значок слева от ответа. В противном случае, вы
   >   можете отреагировать в виде комментариев или правки. Если вы *не*
   >   будете присуждать вознаграждение, половина оного будет автоматически
   >   присуждена ответу, данному после объявления конкурса, с наибольшим
   >   количеством голосов (не менее 2).

Comment: Мало ё. И фидбек всё же англицизм.

Comment: В фексе можно еще глянуть историю.

Comment: @älёxölüt https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/143131397?q=translated%3Ano+text%3A'deserves+your' не вижу там истории по этим фразам.

Comment: точнее, не историю, а предложения. История — это когда оригинал не меняется, а предложения для поиска старых переводов при изменении оригинала незначительно.

Comment: @älёxölüt ага, вижу. Взял за основу и переделал немного.

Comment: Троеточие куда-то потерялось... Но я бы его наверное вовсе заменил на кавычки-ёлочки.

Comment: @älёxölüt в традукире нельзя предложения редактировать. Только удалять и новый перевод предлагать  =/

Comment: редактировать и применить нету, ага. Приходится копипастить и по-новой.

Comment: 10809 какая-то странная строка. С отступами в оригинале.

Comment: Подкорректировал и утвердил.